# I didn’t see the app in my fabric dashboard after a success build

Tags: google-fabric

I just setup my app with Fastlane & fabric Crashlytics and In my console, I have a successful build message :

```
 [23:49:28]: Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta. Time for some ☕️.
 [23:51:08]: Build successfully uploaded to Crashlytics Beta 
 [23:51:08]: Visit https://fabric.io/_/beta to add release notes and notify testers.
```

But I didn’t see the app in my fabric dashboard. What could be the reason?